# Why is my instance variable accessible without an instance?

Tags: java, static, instance-variables

My understanding of the Instance variables is that they are created when an object is created.  If that is true then why can print the variable "data"?  Shouldn't I have to create an object of class `JavaTesting` first?

```
public class JavaTesting 
{
    static int a = 1;
    private int data = 99;

    @Test
    public void f1() 
    {    
        System.out.println("Print a = "+a);
        System.out.println("Print data = "+data);
    }

}
```

Comment: `f1` is an instance method. It's already being run with an instance. The instance is created by JUnit (or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `f1()` is not a static method.  This means it can only be called on an instance.  Whatever method is calling `f1()` is probably creating an instance of `JavaTesting` first.  If you made `f1()` static, your IDE would probably have a fit and start coughing up red flags.